# UWP NavigationView: Two Views under one NavigationViewItem

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to create a `NavigationViewItem` which navigates to two different Views based on a condition.

The UWP app was created using Windows Template Studio and already has the `NavigationView` and default functions to navigate between pages. I want to have the app check for a condition and then either navigate to one or the other View if the user clicks on the `NavigationViewItem`. Also the app should keep the colored line, indicating which View it is on, on the one single `NavigationViewItem`.

This is how my `NavigationView` currently looks like. I would like to combine the `SetTimer` and `WatchTimer` Views. I unfortunately have no idea how the underlying code works as it was all automatically generated and I don't really understand it.

```
<winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_SetTimer" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:SetTimerPage" />
    <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_WatchTimer" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:WatchTimerPage" />
    <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_History" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:HistoryPage" />
</winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

This is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using ShutdownTimer.Helpers;
using ShutdownTimer.Services;

using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

using WinUI = Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ShutdownTimer.Views
{
    public sealed partial class ShellPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly KeyboardAccelerator _altLeftKeyboardAccelerator = BuildKeyboardAccelerator(VirtualKey.Left, VirtualKeyModifiers.Menu);
        private readonly KeyboardAccelerator _backKeyboardAccelerator = BuildKeyboardAccelerator(VirtualKey.GoBack);

        private bool _isBackEnabled;
        private WinUI.NavigationViewItem _selected;

        public bool IsBackEnabled
        {
            get { return _isBackEnabled; }
            set { Set(ref _isBackEnabled, value); }
        }

        public WinUI.NavigationViewItem Selected
        {
            get { return _selected; }
            set { Set(ref _selected, value); }
        }

        public ShellPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            NavigationService.Frame = shellFrame;
            NavigationService.NavigationFailed += Frame_NavigationFailed;
            NavigationService.Navigated += Frame_Navigated;
            navigationView.BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
        }

        private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Keyboard accelerators are added here to avoid showing 'Alt + left' tooltip on the page.
            // More info on tracking issue https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8
            KeyboardAccelerators.Add(_altLeftKeyboardAccelerator);
            KeyboardAccelerators.Add(_backKeyboardAccelerator);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void Frame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw e.Exception;
        }

        private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            IsBackEnabled = NavigationService.CanGoBack;
            if (e.SourcePageType == typeof(SettingsPage))
            {
                Selected = navigationView.SettingsItem as WinUI.NavigationViewItem;
                return;
            }

            Selected = navigationView.MenuItems
                            .OfType<WinUI.NavigationViewItem>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(menuItem => IsMenuItemForPageType(menuItem, e.SourcePageType));
        }

        private bool IsMenuItemForPageType(WinUI.NavigationViewItem menuItem, Type sourcePageType)
        {
            var pageType = menuItem.GetValue(NavHelper.NavigateToProperty) as Type;
            return pageType == sourcePageType;
        }

        private void OnItemInvoked(WinUI.NavigationView sender, WinUI.NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
                return;
            }

            var item = navigationView.MenuItems
                            .OfType<WinUI.NavigationViewItem>()
                            .First(menuItem => (string)menuItem.Content == (string)args.InvokedItem);
            var pageType = item.GetValue(NavHelper.NavigateToProperty) as Type;
            NavigationService.Navigate(pageType);
        }

        private void OnBackRequested(WinUI.NavigationView sender, WinUI.NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }

        private static KeyboardAccelerator BuildKeyboardAccelerator(VirtualKey key, VirtualKeyModifiers? modifiers = null)
        {
            var keyboardAccelerator = new KeyboardAccelerator() { Key = key };
            if (modifiers.HasValue)
            {
                keyboardAccelerator.Modifiers = modifiers.Value;
            }

            keyboardAccelerator.Invoked += OnKeyboardAcceleratorInvoked;
            return keyboardAccelerator;
        }

        private static void OnKeyboardAcceleratorInvoked(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
        {
            var result = NavigationService.GoBack();
            args.Handled = result;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the NavHelper

```
using System;

using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace ShutdownTimer.Helpers
{
    public class NavHelper
    {
        // This helper class allows to specify the page that will be shown when you click on a NavigationViewItem
        //
        // Usage in xaml:
        // <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
        //
        // Usage in code:
        // NavHelper.SetNavigateTo(navigationViewItem, typeof(MainPage));
        public static Type GetNavigateTo(NavigationViewItem item)
        {
            return (Type)item.GetValue(NavigateToProperty);
        }

        public static void SetNavigateTo(NavigationViewItem item, Type value)
        {
            item.SetValue(NavigateToProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigateToProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NavigateTo", typeof(Type), typeof(NavHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you post, the navigation happens in the **OnItemInvoked** event. If you want to have conditions to control the process. That will be the right place. You could set different pagetype in `NavigationService.Navigate(pageType)` according to different conditions.

Besides, I do not recommend you to use the code directly if you don't understand it. The codes contains all the functions but it also means you don't know why and how it works. It might be a better practice if you could try to implement the function by yourself using native code. After you know more about the navigation, then you could understand these code more easily.